# Entanglement generation for commuting Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, hamiltonian-simulation, hamiltonian

Consider an $n$ qubit Hamiltonian $H$ given by
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{i=1}^{m} H_i, 
\end{equation}
where each $H_i$ is a $k$-local term and it holds that
\begin{equation}
e^{H} = e^{H_m} \cdot e^{H_{m-1}} \cdot e^{H_{m-2}} \cdots  e^{H_{2}} e^{H_{1}}.
\end{equation}

Is it, in general, true that
\begin{equation}
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{iH} |0^n\rangle
\end{equation}
will not generate any entanglement? Naively, I would think it is true because each $H_i$ only comprises of a tensor product of single qubit gates which cannot generate entanglement, and hence, $e^{iH_i}$ should also behave in the same way, at every step of the evolution. What am I missing?

Moreover, is there a way to characterize how much entanglement a commuting Hamiltonian generates?

Comment: Do you want the H_k to commute? Or just the (much more restrictive) conditions with the exponentials (where t=1)? In the latter case, I'm sure you can find entangling examples. -- Also note that there are trivial examples which create entnaglement, e.g. two qubits and a single H.